# google map api masterpage coordinate

Tags: asp.net, maps

it's working but when I want to use these code in masterpage I have a problem.
this Problem is about coordinates.
it's looking work but don't take me a coordinates.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.1&sensor=false&language=tr"></script>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/yonetici.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

         function geocodePosition(pos) {
             geocoder.geocode({
                 latLng: pos
             }, function (responses) {
                 if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                     updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
                 } else {
                     updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
                 }
             });
         }

         function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
             document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
         }

         function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
             document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
              latLng.lat(),
              latLng.lng()
            ].join(', ');
         }

         function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
             document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
         }

         function initialize() {
             var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.909450, 34.849715);
             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
                 zoom: 8,
                 center: latLng,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             });
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: latLng,
                 title: 'Point A',
                 map: map,
                 draggable: true
             });

             // Update current position info.
             updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
             geocodePosition(latLng);

             // Add dragging event listeners.
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
                 updateMarkerAddress('Sürükleniyor...');
             });

             document.forms[0].txtLat.value = 40.775146501143766;
             document.forms[0].txtLng.value = 30.384921661376946;
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function () {
                 var latlng = marker.getPosition();
                 document.forms[0].txtLat.value = latlng.lat();
                 document.forms[0].txtLng.value = latlng.lng();
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {

                 geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
             });
         }

         // Onload handler to fire off the app.


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var menu_ul = $('.menu > li > ul'),
               menu_a = $('.menu > li > a');

        menu_ul.hide();

        menu_a.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                menu_a.removeClass('active');
                menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
                $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideDown('normal');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp('normal');
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="ad_googlemaps_area" >

                      <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">


    <div id="info" style="display:none;" ></div>
    <b>Tahmini Adres:</b>
    <div id="address"  ></div>
    <b>Enlem</b>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <b>Boylam:</b>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLng" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>

                </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the onload attribute and initialize method from your body element and javascript both instead put your code inside the pageLoad method as below:

> ```
>   function pageLoad(sender, args) {    //use this method to load your map
>
>      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
>      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.909450, 34.849715);
>
>      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
>         zoom: 8,
>         center: latLng,
>         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>       });
>
>       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>           position: latLng,
>           title: 'Point A',
>           map: map,
>           draggable: true
>       });
>
>          // Update current position info.
>          updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
>          geocodePosition(latLng);
>
>          // Add dragging event listeners.
>          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
>              updateMarkerAddress('Sürükleniyor...');
>          });
>
>          document.forms[0].txtLat.value = 40.775146501143766;
>          document.forms[0].txtLng.value = 30.384921661376946;
>          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function () {
>              var latlng = marker.getPosition();
>              document.forms[0].txtLat.value = latlng.lat();
>              document.forms[0].txtLng.value = latlng.lng();
>          });
>
>          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
>
>              geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
>          });
>
>      function geocodePosition(pos) {
>          geocoder.geocode({
>              latLng: pos
>          }, function (responses) {
>              if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
>                  updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
>              } else {
>                  updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
>              }
>          });
>      }
>
>      function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
>          document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
>      }
>
>      function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
>          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
>           latLng.lat(),
>           latLng.lng()
>         ].join(', ');
>      }
>
>      function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
>          document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
>      }
>
>      // Onload handler to fire off the app.
>
>   }
> ```

Let me know if you still have trouble to load your map.

Answer (score -1):

I try but same problem.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {    //use this method to load your map

 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.909450, 34.849715);

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      title: 'Point A',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
  });

     // Update current position info.
     updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
     geocodePosition(latLng);

     // Add dragging event listeners.
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
         updateMarkerAddre**strong text**ss('Sürükleniyor...');
     });
```

no problems so far

problem Start in here

```
     document.forms[0].txtLat.value = 40.775146501143766;
     document.forms[0].txtLng.value = 30.384921661376946;
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function () {
         var latlng = marker.getPosition();
         document.forms[0].txtLat.value = latlng.lat();
         document.forms[0].txtLng.value = latlng.lng();
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {

         geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
     });

 function geocodePosition(pos) {
     geocoder.geocode({
         latLng: pos
     }, function (responses) {
         if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
             updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
         } else {
             updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
         }
     });
 }

 function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
     document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
 }

 function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
      latLng.lat(),
      latLng.lng()
    ].join(', ');
 }

 function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
     document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
 }

 // Onload handler to fire off the app.
```

}